# Django : ModelFormset validation not properly work

Tags: django, django-forms, django-validation

**models.py**

```
class OrderImage(TimeStampedModel):
    image = models.ImageField()
```

**forms.py**

```
class OrderImageForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = OrderImage
        fields = ('image',)
```

Then, I submit my form without any image file in `my.html`

And I break the `views.py` with `embed()` for debugging.

**views.py**

```
.
.
.
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    from django.forms import modelformset_factory
    OrderImageFormSet = modelformset_factory(
        OrderImage, form=OrderImageForm
    )
    order_image_formset = OrderImageFormSet(
        request.POST,
        request.FILES,
        queryset=OrderImage.objects.none()
    )
    from IPython import embed; embed();
```

First, `check request.FILES`

```
In [5]: request.FILES
Out[5]: <MultiValueDict: {}>
```

Here, I test two things.

**1. order_image_formset validation.**

```
In [4]: order_image_formset.is_valid()
Out[4]: True
```

> it shows `True`, even though there is no image file.

**2. OrderImageForm validation **

```
In [1]: order_image_form = OrderImageForm(request.FILES)

In [2]: order_image_form.is_valid()
Out[2]: False

In [3]: order_image_form.errors
Out[3]: {'image': ['필수 항목입니다.']}
```

> It says, `image` field is required.

I don't know why `modelformset` doesn't check validation correctly.

Any Idea?

Comment: Because a formset only validates a form if it has data in it; since you have no data at all, it doesn't instantiate any forms, so the whole thing is valid.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, then how can I deal with it? Do I have to extend `BaseFormset` and redefine class ?